# PowerShell Modules are not recognized in Docker Container

Tags: docker, powershell

I want to run a PowerShell script in a docker container.
The script uses some PowerShell Modules from the PowerShell Gallery.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./export_tenant.ps1 /app
SHELL ["pwsh", "-command"]
RUN Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement -RequiredVersion 3.0.0 -Confirm:$false
RUN Install-Module AzureADPreview -Confirm:$false
RUN Install-Module MSOnline -Confirm:$false
RUN Install-Module MicrosoftTeams -Confirm:$false 
RUN Install-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -Confirm:$false
RUN Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -Confirm:$false

CMD ["pwsh", "-File", "export_tenant.ps1"]
```

After successfully building the image, I start the container but I get errors from all the missing modules.

```
Get-MsolCompanyInformation: /app/export_tenant.ps1:149
Line |
 149 |  $PasswordSynchronizationEnabled = Get-MsolCompanyInformation | select …
     |                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'Get-MsolCompanyInformation' is not recognized as a
     | name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable
     | program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
     | included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Module msonline is incompatible with Powershell core

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).